# Loops in Python

Tags: python, while-loop

I need to create a loop in python and stop just after I get to 1000. At present, it looks like it stops just before the loop hits 1000 and I need it to go one more value.

```
var = 3.0
while var < 1000:
    print(Var)
    Var = var * 2.1
```

Comment: `while var <= 1000`?

Comment: It doesn't work. I need it to go one value past 1000.

Comment: Then .maybe `while True` and then check `if var > 1000`?

Comment: `while var < 1002` ?

Comment: Should `Var` be `var` in side the loop statement

Comment: This looks to create an infinite loop. Nothing to stop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common scenario. Just do the last iteration outside of the loop.

```
var = 3.0
while var < 1000:
    print(var)
    var = var * 2.1
print(var) # here var will be equal to its value one step after passing 1000
```

This will give you your desired behavior. Alternatively, do the first iteration before the loop:

```
var = 3.0
print(var)
while var < 1000:
    var = var * 2.1
    print(var)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is IMO ugly, but I've seen it often used to solve the lack of the type of loop you need in Python.

```py
var = 3.0
while True:
    print(var)
    if var >= 1000:
        break
    var = var * 2.1
```

Would this do what you had in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't simply want to do this:

```
var = 3.0
while var < 1000:
     var = var * 2.1
     print(var)
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic problem here is that you're trying to print the initial value of the loop index, as well as one *past* the last value.  If you loop 10 times, you need to print 11 values.  Therefore, you *must* have one `print` *outside* of your loop.

The most obvious way (IMHO) is to print the initial value separately, and then let your loop do a change-print-check order, rather than the opposite.

```
var = 3.0
print(var)
while var < 1000:
    var = var * 2.1
    print(var)
```

Output:

3.0

```
6.300000000000001
13.230000000000002
27.783000000000005
58.34430000000001
122.52303000000003
257.2983630000001
540.3265623000002
1134.6857808300006
```